# In CALCULATE, what is the difference between using FILTER(ALL...) vs not using FILTER (that is - only using ALL) - example below?

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

Instead of the above, can we write:

```
US Sales = CALCULATE(SUM(FactInternetSales[SalesAmount]),ALL(DimSalesTerritory)
                     ,DimSalesTerritory[SalesTerritoryCountry]="United States"
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another one of your questions that can be answered with more or less the same answer: Syntax sugar! Your two queries are identical under the hood.

Also note the difference between the below:

```
US Sales = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( FactInternetSales[SalesAmount] ) ,
        DimSalesTerritory[SalesTerritoryCountry] = "United States"
    )
```

which is syntax sugar for:

```
US Sales = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( FactInternetSales[SalesAmount] ) ,
        FILTER ( 
            ALL ( DimSalesTerritory[SalesTerritoryCountry] ), 
            DimSalesTerritory[SalesTerritoryCountry] = "United States"
        )
    )
```

But note that the `ALL` clause evaluates the single column and not the whole `DimSalesTerritory` table. Filter context on the other columns in that table are preserved.

Comment: So logically it's the same, just syntax differs?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.